# Openssl + Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, archlinux, linux, c

if I code a program with openssl on a Ubuntu laptop will it work when it is compiled on the Raspberry Pi or are the libraries are different?

does the command

`sudo apt-get install openssl`

work on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Which distro are you usig you have the question tagged as both Arch and Raspbian? What language is the code written in? Assuming you are running the Raspbian or Occidentalis distribution (both of which are based on Debian) sudo apt-get will work on the Pi.

Comment: I'm still hesitating which one I'm gonna use maybe also I choose debian but I will have problem in memory at that time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libraries should be compatible unless a completely different major version has been installed. Keep in mind that the Pi is ARM while your Ubuntu system is probably x86. Any software will need to be recompiled, which means you'll need gcc, etc., installed from the build-essential package. You'll also need all the relevant dev packages. On that note, bear in mind that openssl is a binary utilities package, you probably want libssl and libssl-dev if you're using the libraries directly.

Comment: so I should not really worry too much about functions that I'm using ?

Comment: No it should be fine. That's the whole point of libraries. :)